# RESTEasy on JBoss 5 - jars needed

Tags: jboss5.x, resteasy

We are running JBoss 5.1.0 and I'm trying to get just a simple test app up and running with RESTEasy. However, I cannot figure out what I need in order to do this. Apparently new versions of JBoss have everything included, but that doesn't help me. From what I understand, I need to modify the web.xml of my app to include the bootstrap and some other things. And then I need to include some jars in the WEB-INF/lib. This is where I'm stuck.

- Do I need to include any jars in the server/lib in JBoss, or are they all supposed to be in the WEB-INF/lib of my app?
- What jars do I need to include? We are not using Maven. I've seen very few tutorials actually mention which jars to use, and when I download RESTEasy there 65 jars in the lib folder. I'm not including 65 jars in my HelloWorld app just to get RESTEasy to run. I can't find any documentation that tells me plainly what I need in order to get a RESTEasy app up and running on JBoss 5

Comment: Could you provide links to the resources that helped you set up RESTEasy on JBoss 5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resteasy libraries are not bundled with JBOSS.5.1.0.
You should include following libraries in your WEB-INF/lib

[image]

Comment: Thanks Prasobh...you saved me a lot of work porting from Wildfly to JBoss :)

Answer (score 1):

To add to Prasobh.K's answer - if using the pom.xml in a maven project setup - then you can just add the following inside the dependencies tags:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scannotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>scannotation</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

(instead of copying the jars into the lib folder)

It may also help some doing a port from Wildfly to JBoss 5.1 that the 
...**\WEB-INF\web.xml** should be changed to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

from the wildfly version which is:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
```

Comment: Thanks Prasobh...you saved me a lot of work porting from Wildfly to JBoss :)