# why is the scope of RestEasy compile in the pom.xml when the container (JBOSS) provides it?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, resteasy

Here is the relevant portion of pom.xml

```
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-all-5.0</artifactId>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
```

Why is the scope of `resteasy` *compile* (which is default, when none is provided) but that of `javax.servlet` is *provided*. I am deploying this on `Jboss` which ships with `resteasy`. so shouldn't the scope of `resteasy` be *provided* as well?

and btw, I do not see any version mentioned. so what is the default version that gets picked up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using jboss 7, resteasy-jackson-provider is included, so it would be correct to use a provided scope.

I guess default version is being picked up from a bom declared in the dependencyManagement section of your pom, could that be right?

For older jboss versions, resteasy is not included, so you will have to add the jars to your WEB-INF/lib directory.

Necessary jars can be obtained using maven (compile scope) or check out this link http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/resteasy/resteasy-tutorial

Comment: I am using jboss 5, do you think it is necessary?

Comment: yes, it is necessary because jboss 5 does not include resteasy jars

Answer (score 1):

The RESTEasy API and runtime is provided by newer versions of JBoss. Usually you import a Java EE-spec pom in the dependencyManagaement section and add the needed APIs in the dependency section, e.g for JBoss AS7:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The runtime will use the JSON-Provider which is found on the classpath. So it makes sense to add them with scope `compile` to your project. If you want to use Jettison you'd add following to your pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-jettison-provider</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you don't add one your application server may provide a default one. JBoss AS7 / Wildfly for instance will use `resteasy-jackson-provider` if you don't add a provider to the classpath.
JBoss 5 does not provide the JAX-RS libs [as far as I know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13066969/1353722) so there it makes sense to add the `resteasy-jackson-provider` with scope `compile`.

Comment: Thanks, as for JBoss 5, since it does not provide `resteasy-jackson-provider`, if adding with scope `compile` sufficient. when I deploy, will there by any issues for run-time dependencies. Also when I package, will the `resteasy-jackson-provider jar` gets included?

Comment: Yes, resteasy-jackson-provider will be included. I don't think you will have runtime dependencies, but you will have to try that out. You can find resteasy config for jboss 5 here http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/resteasy/resteasy-tutorial